# Changing GPS for 2 to 1 location

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps, location

I'm trying to change GPS from 2 locations to 1 location

The code for 2 locations is:

```
ismi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String CURRENT_LOCATION = "37.967775, 23.720689";
        String DESTINATION_LOCATION = "37.925942, 23.938683";

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ CURRENT_LOCATION +"&daddr="+DESTINATION_LOCATION)); //Added ampersand
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
});
```

And to change to one location like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCvW5.png

I even changed on part but it takes from my location to the destination location

Code:

```
ismi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String DESTINATION_LOCATION = "37.925942, 23.938683";

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +"&daddr="+DESTINATION_LOCATION)); //Added ampersand
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
});
```

Does anyone know the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start an `Intent` that will take you to a single GPS location, use:

```
   String DESTINATION_LOCATION = "37.925942,23.938683";
   Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
   Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+DESTINATION_LOCATION));
   startActivity(intent);
```

The `URI` contains The `GPS` coordinates as you defined previously. Note that there should be no spaces between latitude and longitude values in your `DESTINATION_LOCATION` `String`.

Edit: As response to your first question in your comment, to give a name to the label:

```
    String DESTINATION_LOCATION = "My location name";
    String latit = "37.925942";
    String longit = "23.938683";
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("geo:<"+latit+">,<"+longit+">?q=<"+latit+">,<"+longit+">("+DESTINATION_LOCATION+")")); //name the label
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) just two questions if you don't mind .. (1) is there away to write the location name myself with it? like, the marker and the name .. (2) is there away to change the marker with a small picture I have? I am not using API

Comment: The last question if may I ask? :) The Marker, does it have anything to do with the API key?

Comment: No, it hasn't. The API key is different for each application and a Marker is just a visual pointer that you can place on the map.